# AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'dtype'

Tags: python, numpy, keras

When I try to use a custom activation function in keras (2.2.5), I create a new activation function gelu.
add it in activations.py :

```
from . import backend as K    
import numpy as np
def gelu(x):
    return 0.5 * x * (1 + K.tanh(K.sqrt(2 / np.pi) * (x + 0.044715 * K.pow(x, 3))))
```

use it in my main.py :

```
cnn1 = Conv1D(filters=256, kernel_size=2, strides=1, padding="same")(gru_output)
cnn1 = Activation('gelu')(cnn1)
```

But I get a error when working it:

```
File "C:/Users/user/Desktop/my/my_main.py", line 253, in <module>
    cnn1 = Activation('gelu')(cnn1)
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop/my\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 451, in __call__
    output = self.call(inputs, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\my\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\core.py", line 300, in call
    return self.activation(inputs)
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\my\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\activations.py", line 16, in gelu
    return 0.5 * x * (1 + K.tanh(K.sqrt(2 / np.pi) * (x + 0.044715 * K.pow(x, 3))))
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\my\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 1675, in sqrt
    zero = _to_tensor(0., x.dtype.base_dtype)
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'dtype'
```

So what should i do?

Comment: GELU is already available in the TF Keras package. See [`tf.keras.activations.gelu`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/activations/gelu)

Comment: i know it, but my version of tensorflow is only 1.13.1, this version cant use gelu directly

Answer (score 0):

Replace `K.sqrt()` with `tf.math.sqrt()`